# sql query to select records from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Can suggest me the best way to select records from MySQL

```
customer
--------
id  bed_id  status
1   1       vocated     
2   1       booked
3   2       vocated

bed
-----
id  name
1   lower 
2   middle
3   upper
```

I need to select bed which are vacated or not allotted

Here, the expected results are 
The empty bed should be: bed_id's = 2 and 3
what is best SQL query to get this kind of result

Comment: Define 'best'!! And show us what you've tried

Comment: What do you have against sub queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and group by the bed's id and put the conditions in a HAVING clause:

```
select b.id, b.name
from bed b left join customer c
on c.bed_id = b.id
group by b.id
having (
  sum(status = 'vacated') > 0
  and
  sum(status = 'booked') = 0
) or sum(status is null) > 0
```

I'm not sure if you need `and` or `or` in the conditions

Comment: this query gives 1 and 2 as "bed id"

Comment: Now it gives 2 and 3

Comment: well, after the change :)

Comment: Thank you @forpas. i was expecting the same in a single join query

Comment: This is a single join but it does grouping afterwards and aggregate to check the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT * FROM bed
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT bed_id FROM customer
    WHERE Status = 'booked'
)
```

**Note:** This wll work for your current data. But if I think practical, you need to check the latest status of a BED in the customer table. That case you need to provide data with more variety and more explanation of your requirement.

Comment: Thank you.  looking for a query with joining the table and its not with a subquery.

Comment: Id in customer table is incremental? For BED_id 1 there are 2 entry with ID 1 & 2. Is that true that Bigest ID 2 hold the latest status of Bed_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a reverse logic by `not exists` :

```
select *
  from bed b
 where not exists 
  (
   select bed_id
     from customer
    where status != 'vocated' and status = 'booked'
      and bed_id = b.id);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=14c7a260146b3f0c10da43f9d7f1bf3a)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You could find the most recent status using a correlated sub query and a left join to find rooms that have never had activity

```
 select group_concat(s.t1id) availablerooms 
    from
    (
    select t1.id t1id,t1.name,t.id,t.bed_id,t.status
    from t1
    left join t on t1.id = t.bed_id 
    where t.id = (select max(id) from t where t1.id = t.bed_id) or
            t.id is null
    ) s
    where s.status <> 'booked' or s.status is null;

+----------------+
| availablerooms |
+----------------+
| 2,3            |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```